# How to sum up in two vector without overriding the results

Tags: r, loops, vector, sum

I would like to sum up two vectors, in a way that:

```
A = seq(10, 30, 10)
B = seq(1, 6, 1)
C = c()

for (i in B) {
  for (j in A)
  C = c(j + i)
}
```

C would be a vector with all results appearing from:

```
for (i in B) {
  for (j in A)
  print(j + i)
}
```

I am not interested in a matrix for this. What could I possibly do?
Thanks

Comment: you can use the append() function instead of c() within your loop

Comment: append()? I gave it a try but it is not clear how I should arrange it. i would invite to provide some example

Comment: @Feelfree See if you will post as answer, if so, I'll delete it from my answer :)

Comment: @benson23 Nuuuuuh, im good. You did it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer` in this case.

```r
c(outer(A, B, `+`))
[1] 11 21 31 12 22 32 13 23 33 14 24 34 15 25 35 16 26 36
```

---

If you really need a for loop, we can use the approach provided by @Feel free in the comment:

```r
for (i in B) {
  for (j in A)
    C = append(C, j + i)
}

C
[1] 11 21 31 12 22 32 13 23 33 14 24 34 15 25 35 16 26 36
```